# KivyMD - MDTabs - How to get current active tab name?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I need to get current Tab's name. I checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320966/kivymd-how-to-get-active-tab-in-mdtab). And tried this code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.app import MDApp
kv = Builder.load_string("""
<SM>
    P1:
<P1>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'TEST'
        MDTabs:
            id: toolbar
            on_tab_switch: root.give_current_tab_name()
            Tab:
                text: 'Tab 1'
            Tab:
                text: 'Tab 2'
            Tab:
                text: 'Tab 3'
""")
class P1(Screen):
    def give_current_tab_name(self):
        print(self.ids.toolbar.carousel.current_slide.tab_label.text) #It gives previous tab name...
class Tab(FloatLayout,MDTabsBase):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

But, it gives me previous Tab's name.Should i use schedule_once(testfunc,delay_time) for check current tab's name or is there a any other easy way to do that?

Also, i need to **disallow to slide page for change tab**.It must be only from top tab's names.Can anyone help me for these problems. Thanks already..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting tabs name,
on_tab_switch pass 4 arguments:

instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text

so you can write something like this:

```
MDTabs:
    id: toolbar
    on_tab_switch: root.give_current_tab_name(*args)
```

...

```
def give_current_tab_name(self, *args):
    tab_name = args[3]
```

For disallowing sliding,
just add:

```
MDTabs:
    id: toolbar
    on_tab_switch: root.give_current_tab_name(*args)
    lock_swiping: True
```